# Variable can be of two different types

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on a use case where I use the ECB Loan Data Templates. The problem I ran into is, that variables can be of two different types. E.g. the field "Date of the Financial Statements at Underwriting" can be of type `Date` and also of type `NoData` which is a Enum. How can I construct this in Kotlin?

I'm looking for something like:

```
val dateOfTheFinancialStatementsAtUnderwriting: Date || NoData
```

Would a custom class which wraps these two types be a proper way to handle this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the use of NoData? You could make Date nullable and use the null state to derive there is no data, or if you need the NoData enum for some reason then you probably want a wrapper object yes

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The NoData Enum represents information on why there is no data present and can have 6 different reasons, so this is (sadly) not replaceable by being nullable.

Comment: have you considered using https://arrow-kt.io/docs/datatypes/either/ ?

Comment: Oh wow, thanks @kris_k that looks promising and easy. Do you know if Either serializes properly to the underlying type?

Comment: @lennertr I am not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate a little bit on: "Either serializes properly to the underlying type"?

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding. I need to de-/serialize variables of type `Either` through Jackson and my question is if this works.

Comment: To sum up subject of serialization: it seems it is too complex to discuss it using comments only and @lennertr asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119382/de-serialization-of-either-through-jackson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kris_k says, you can use the data type Either. If you don't want to add a library (Arrow), you can define it yourself with a sealed class:

```
sealed class Either<out L, out R> {

    data class Left<out L>(val a: L) : Either<L, Nothing>()

    data class Right<out R>(val b: R) : Either<Nothing, R>()

    val isLeft: Boolean get() = this is Left<L>
    val isRight: Boolean get() = this is Right<R>
}
```

How to return an `Either`:

```
class Date
class NoData

fun getDateOfTheFinancialStatementsAtUnderwriting(): Either<NoData, Date> {
    if (...) {
        return Either.Left(NoData())
    } else {
        return Either.Right(Date())
    }
}
```

How to use the `Either`:

```
val result: Either<NoData, Date> = getDateOfTheFinancialStatementsAtUnderwriting()

when (result) {
    is Either.Left -> {
        val noData: NoData = result.a
        TODO()
    }
    is Either.Right -> {
        val date: Date = result.b
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JavierSA . The only issue I run into is deserialization through Jackson. I tried adding type annotations like this `@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="class")` but I still get an error when deserializing: `Failed to encode as JSON`. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: No, I don't. :( But, why do you need to de-/serialize an `Either`? Are you working with REST, sending or receiving JSONs? This is how I use `Either` in client apps when I make petitions to servers: a) I receive the server response in JSON format, b) I convert it to an error or the data I want and, then, I wrap it in an `Either` (I return a `Left` or a `Right`), c) top layer receives an `Either` and can decide what to do in case of error or in case of success.

Comment: I'm using Braid (https://gitlab.com/bluebank/braid) to pass json data between my backend and frontend, this handles the connection via Websockets. I think I need to add proper annotations to the Either class you described or use Jackson MixIn. But thanks for your help :)